# How to add widget to Dojo gridx/Grid header?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo.gridx

I have gridx/Grid (http://oria.github.io/gridx/) and I want to add some widgets in header cells like textboxes, dropdowns etc. Is there a way to put widget in header cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you need is a module called `HeaderRegions`. Here is it's [API](http://oria.github.io/gridx/apidoc/#1.3/gridx/modules/HeaderRegions)
. Especially note the `add` and `refresh` methods.

For a simple example take a look [here](https://github.com/oria/gridx/blob/master/tests/test_grid_headerRegions.js).

To affect only one column header, use a predicate on the argument (column) provided by the callback that is the first argument of `add` (easiest would be to use the column id).

To insert a widget, create it programatically, fire it's `startup` method and return it's `domNode` attribute.

(I am not sure but it may be that `startup` should be called **after** the grid is rendered. For this you may have to keep a reference to the widget outside the method)

For completeness, I include the some of the example linked above:

```js
Deferred.when(parser.parse(), function() {
  var hr = grid1.headerRegions;
  hr.add(function(col) {
    return domConstruct.create('div', {
      style: 'height: 13px; width: 10px; background-color: red;'
    });
  }, 0, 0);
  hr.add(function(col) {
    return domConstruct.create('div', {
      style: 'height: 13px; width: 10px; background-color: green;'
    });
  }, 1, 0);
  hr.refresh();
});
```

Comment: Yes, this helped me to insert widget into header.

Comment: @massimo: How could you achieve this? When using the code snippet from the answer my gridx doesn't change at all showing no errors in the console?

Comment: ok, by adding "display: block" it's at least right next to the header text. Before it was only visible when I hovered over the header. Any idea how to move it below the text?
[link_to_jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ynqhk2L/3/)

Comment: `grid.headerRegions` only lets you add nodes floating to the right of the header. To have complete control over the header node try to use [Header.getHeaderNode()](http://oria.github.io/gridx/apidoc/#1.2/gridx/modules/Header)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can there is a plugin for the datagrid that you can add textbox and other input stuff within the layout.
example of a layout

```
var layout = [
    {name: 'Index', field: 'id'},
    {name: 'Date', field: 'date', width: 10,
        formatter: formatDate,                // Custom format, change the format in store.
        editable: true,                       // Editable cell
        type: dojox.grid.cells.DateTextBox,   // Use DateTextBox in editing mode
        getValue: getDateValue,               // Translate the value of DateTextBox to something the store can understand.
        constraint: {formatLength: 'long'}    // Format the date value shown in DateTextBox
    }
];
```

or this is more complete example

```
require(["dojox/grid/DataGrid", "dojox/grid/cells", "dojox/grid/cells/dijit",
"dojo/date/locale", "dojo/currency", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dijit/form/CurrencyTextBox",
"dijit/form/HorizontalSlider", "dojo/domReady!"
], function(DataGrid, cells, cellsDijit, locale, currency, DateTextBox, CurrencyTextBox, HorizontalSlider){
function formatCurrency(inDatum){
    return isNaN(inDatum) ? '...' : currency.format(inDatum, this.constraint);
}
function formatDate(inDatum){
    return locale.format(new Date(inDatum), this.constraint);
}
gridLayout = [{
    defaultCell: { width: 8, editable: true, type: cells._Widget, styles: 'text-align: right;'  },
    cells: [
        { name: 'Id', field: 'id', editable: false, width: 2 /* Can't edit ID's of dojo/store items */ },
        { name: 'Date', field: 'col8', width: 10, editable: true,
            widgetClass: DateTextBox,
            formatter: formatDate,
            constraint: {formatLength: 'long', selector: "date"}},
        { name: 'Priority', styles: 'text-align: center;', field: 'col1', width: 10,
            type: cells.ComboBox,
            options: ["normal","note","important"]},
        { name: 'Mark', field: 'col2', width: 5, styles: 'text-align: center;',
            type: cells.CheckBox},
        { name: 'Status', field: 'col3',
            styles: 'text-align: center;',
            type: cells.Select,
            options: ["new", "read", "replied"] },
        { name: 'Message', field: 'col4', styles: '', width: 10 },
        { name: 'Amount', field: 'col5', formatter: formatCurrency, constraint: {currency: 'EUR'},
            widgetClass: CurrencyTextBox, width: "auto" },
        { name: 'Amount', field: 'col5', formatter: formatCurrency, constraint: {currency: 'EUR'},
            widgetClass: HorizontalSlider, width: 10}
    ]
}];
```

remember you need to add `dojo.require("dojox.grid.cells.dijit");`

you can read about it [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/griddate.html)

**UPDATE** here is the gridx example

```
var grid = new Grid({
  cacheClass: 'gridx/core/model/cache/Async',
  store: someStore,
  structure: [
    { id: 'progress', field: 'progress', name: 'Install Progress',
      widgetsInCell: true,
      decorator: function(){
          return "<input type="text" name='firstname' value='testing testing'  data-dojo-type='dijit/form/TextBox' data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true" id='firstname' />";
      }
    }
  ],
  modules: [
    "gridx/modules/CellWidget"
  ]
});
```

for more details have a read [here](https://github.com/oria/gridx/wiki/How-to-show-widgets-in-gridx-cells%3F)

**UPDATE2** 
Okay if I understand you correctly now when you create a gridx each layout name field will have the field name in it associated with grid- prefix so if the header you want to change is the `name` header you need use grid-prefix to replace the value or inject it with html

```
   //Clear the value inside the grid
     domConstruct.empty("grid-name")
//place a textbox in the header
    require(["dijit/form/TextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(TextBox){
        var myTextBox = new dijit.form.TextBox({
            name: "firstname",
            value: "" /* no or empty value! */,
            placeHolder: "type in your name"
        }, "grid-name");
    });
```

Comment: This is a DataGrid example, I think this won't work for gridx/Grid (http://oria.github.io/gridx/).

Comment: Try it should work fine for basic implementation take a look at this too http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/gridx-combobox-with-label-value-pairs-td3994788.html

Comment: I added an update for the gridx if you want to make more custom widget

Comment: I've tried the last update and it renders widgets in all cells of column but not in the header cell.

Comment: So I can understand what you exactly want, you want ot replace the field header name with a drop down box or an input box?

Comment: I want to see header name and textbox **both** in header cell. Textbox will be used as filter input.

Comment: okay do what I said in update2 but without the `domConstruct.empty("grid-name")`