# Checkbox in particular header column of gridx

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using gridx and trying to add a checkbox on the Header region of the grid where certain actions will be performed. The checkbox should not be on all the header columns (it has to be at a particular column)

I tried using headerRegions.

```
    var hr = grid.headerRegions;
    hr.add(function(col){
        return domConstruct.create('div', {
            id: 'columnHeaderDiv',
            style: 'height: 13px; width: 30px; display: inline-block'
        });
    }, 1, 0);
    hr.refresh();

    var row = domConstruct.toDom("<input id='mycheck' name='mycheck' data-dojo-type='dijit/form/CheckBox' value='agreed' checked onChange=\"alert('onChange called with parameter = ' + arguments[0] + ', and widget value = ' + this.get('value'))\" />");
    domConstruct.place(row, "columnHeaderDiv");
    grid.startup();
```

The output i got is:
[Header Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb4zq.png)

However, I need checkbox on "Column2", "Column3", "Column4" and not on "Column1"

I went through the link [How to add widget to Dojo gridx/Grid header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752264/how-to-add-widget-to-dojo-gridx-grid-header)
In the above link there is a line which says "**To affect only one column header, use a predicate on the argument (column) provided by the callback that is the first argument of add (easiest would be to use the column id)**". I didn't understand this line. Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hr.add(function(col){
//here the col will have index like 0,1,2 etc... and also id. You can do a check here like or you can do it on ID as well
if(col.index!==1){
return domConstruct.create('div', {
            id: 'columnHeaderDiv',
            style: 'height: 13px; width: 30px; display: inline-block'
        });
}

    }, 1, 0);
    hr.refresh();
```

Comment: I tried before, using ID, and that worked, but thanks for letting me know that I can do it using index too. :)